# Help with Linear Transformations Proof

Tags: linear-algebra

So here is the (probably simple) proof:

Assume that T:V $\rightarrow$ V is a linear operator on the vector space V, that v $\neq$0 and that the set {v, T(v), T$^2$(v),...,T$^{k-1}$(v)} is independent but the set {v, T(v), T$^2$(v),...,T$^{k-1}$(v), T$^k$(v)} is dependent. Let U=span(v, T(v), T$^2$(v),...,T$^{k-1}$(v)). Show that for all w $\in$ U, T(w) $\in$ U.

I'm not really sure how I should approach this proof. My first thought is to extend the basis of V with another basis, but the proof isn't coming to me.  I would greatly appreciate your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, when you're told that $\left\{v, T(v), T^{2}(v),...,T^{k−1}(v)\right\}$ is linearly independent, but that $\left\{v, T(v), T^{2}(v),...,T^{k}(v)\right\}$ is not, what does that tell you about what $T^{k}\left(v\right)$ looks like? Think about the definition of linear independence.

Now, think about what $w\in U$ looks like. We know that $w$ has to be something of the form $w=c_{0}v+c_{1}T\left(v\right)+\cdots+c_{k-1}T^{k-1}\left(v\right)$, where the $c_{i}$ are scalars in your field. Then, what does $T\left(w\right)$ look like? Think about the linearity of $T$.

When you look at your last term, you'll notice that you already have something to put there in terms of the basis vectors of $U$. So, you have shown that $T\left(w\right)\in U$, as required.

Comment: So T(w) =  T(c$_0$v+c$_1$T(v)+c$_2$T$^2$(v)+...+c$_{k-1}$T$^{k-1}$(v))= c$_0$T(v)+c$_1$T(T(v))+c$_2$T(T$^2$(v))+...+c$_{k-1}$T(T$^{k-1}$(v))? The notation looks odd.

Comment: For a linear operator $T$, remember that $T^{m}\left(T^{n}\left(v\right)\right) = T^{m+n}\left(v\right)$. So, when you've gone through the linearity step, you'll have a bunch of $T\left(T^{n}\left(v\right)\right)$ terms, where $1\leq n < k$. You just add the exponents of the operators. So, with this information, what is the last term, and how can you represent it using the basis vectors of $U$?

Comment: I didn't even think about applying the power rule. Applying the rule, I observe that the last term is c$_{k-1}$T$^k$(v). This is the last vector in the dependent set given. I am still not seeing what you are trying to guide me to find with the vector.

Comment: Now, since the set including the $T^{k}\left(v\right)$ is dependent, that means that there exist scalars $b_{0},\ldots,b_{k}$ that are not all zero such that $b_{0}v + b_{1}T\left(v\right)+\cdots+b_{k}T^{k}\left(v\right) = 0$. Note that since the set without the $T^{k}\left(v\right)$ is independent, this forces $b_{k}\neq0$ (can you see why?). So, how can you manipulate $b_{0}v+b_{1}T\left(v\right)+\cdots+b_{k}T^{k}\left(v\right) = 0$ to get $T^{k}\left(v\right)$ in terms of $v,T\left(v\right),\ldots,T^{k-1}\left(v\right)$?

Comment: So T$^k$=-$^1/b$^k$(b$_0$v+b$_1$T(v)+b$_2$T$^2$(v)+...+b$_{k-1}$T$^{k-1}$

Comment: Yes, so when you plug that in for the $c_{k-1}T^{k}\left(v\right)$ term and combine like terms, what can you finally conclude about $T\left(w\right)$?

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much for your help. I greatly appreciate your time and effort.